# Same height on DFS trees

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation, algorithms

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a directed graph.

We have a node $s \in V$ that has a path to all the nodes in $G$.

The question asks to show that any Depth-First Search will give a tree with the same height.

Initially, I thought the question meant Breadth-First Search, but then I constructed a graph that shows two BFS trees with different heights.

I really don't know how to start to tackle the problem.

Comment: Does the DFS start at $s$?

Comment: Have you misread the question? Consider the digraph $D=(V,A)$ with $V=\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ and $A=\{(a,b),(b,d),(d,e),(a,c),(c,e)\}$. Then the DFS tree rooted at $a$ and traversing $(a,b)$ first has height 4, whereas the one that starts by traversing $(a,c)$ has height 3. Are the paths from $s$ unique?

Comment: Thank you for bringing my attention.

It does say that the DFS start at s.

It does not say that the paths from s unique.

Comment: The question asks to proof which from the following statement are correct: 
statement 1 - All the DFS trees rooted is s have the same height. 
statement 2 - All the BFS trees rooted is s have the same height. 
For the wrong statement the question aske to give an example for a graph G that the ration between two BFS/DFS tree will be the biggest as possible.
I want to apologize for my claim - The trees I constructed had a different root on the BFS tree.

Comment: In this case, I think that statement 2 is the right one.
Here is my attempt to proof it:
In layer i in the BFS tree, there will be the nodes that have a path of i from s.
The time that each node will be scanned will not violate this fact.
There for, all the BFS tree rooted is s will have the height.

Comment: Since there is no way to reach a vertex at distance $d$ from $s$ until the BFS traversal has reached its $d$th tier, you are right that no BFS tree can have height less than $d_\mbox{max}$, the largest distance of any vertex from $s$. Nor, clearly, can any BFS traversal reach a $(d_\mbox{max}+1)$st tier. So every BFS tree has height $d_\mbox{max}$.

Comment: Thank you very much!